# jooq UTC localdatetime changes between save and load

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jooq, localdatetime

My coworker created a postgresql database using jooq. Since then, we created objects with fields and the value of LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC). When those get saved to this database and read again later a few hours changed in our data object:

```
public class PlannedInvoice
{
    private UUID accountId;
    private LocalDateTime billingTime;
}
```

The save method looks similar to this:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
UUID accountId = UUID.randomUUID();

PlannedinvoiceRecord record = plannedInvoiceService.create();
record.setAccountid(accountId.toString());
record.setBillingtime(now.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
record.store();
```

And the read method like this:

```
return dsl.selectFrom(PLANNEDINVOICE)
        .where(PLANNEDINVOICE.ACCOUNTID.eq(accountId.toString()))
        .fetchOneInto(PlannedInvoice.class);
```

The database uses `timestamp with time zone` currently, but I would also be happy to replace it with actual LocalDateTime to avoid these problems altogether([JOOQ supports this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-generate-java-time-types/))!

When we save a value of `LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.AUGUST, 13, 0, 0)`, it will be `2020-08-12 20:00:00-04` in the database. This still seems correct.

Reading the value from the database seems where things go wrong. After the read method the value of billingTime is 2020-08-12 20:00:00. It seems to me like the time zone gets ignored by `fetchOneInto` when reconstructing the data object.

So why is there a conversion when saving UTC values and why is there no conversion when reading those back from the database? This seems very counterintuitive to me. I would prefer to avoid any time zone conversions at all.

Comment: Please provide an example of the time that went in and how it came out. Also what is the data type for the field the datetime is being stored in?  Also what is the ```timezone``` set in the Postgres server as well as the time zone on the machine this code is being run on? Why is ```ZoneOffset.UTC``` used twice on now?

Comment: Why not use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (and either `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, (default in jOOQ and JDBC), or `java.time.Instant`) data types, instead? Otherwise, both your server (PostgreSQL) and client (Java) timezone settings will get in the way all the time, if they're not aligned.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added an example date. My machine where I tested is set to UTC-05. If I run 'show timezone;' on my local PostgreSQL, it returns "US/Eastern". I would prefer a solution that is not dependent on that though, so I would not get the problem of "but it works on my machine".

Comment: @LukasEder Currently it uses 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE' already. Is the combination with OffsetDateTime the only reliable one working with jooq? We did not have this issue with JPA before using JOOQ.

Comment: If you are working with timestamps they are always going to be dependent on time zones, unless you keep everything in UTC(which itself is a time zone:)). Do **not** change the ```timestamp with time zone``` to one without, that will only make things worse. What you are seeing is ```select '2020-09-12 20:00:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'US/Eastern'; 09/12/2020 20:00:00```. I'm guessing this is something your framework is doing

Comment: I am keeping everything in UTC. At least I was before the db round trip.

Comment: If your db field is ```timestamp with time zone``` then it is being stored as ```UTC```. The ```2020-09-12 20:00:00-04``` you see is just formatting applied because you are looking at timestamp in client with ```timezone='US/Eastern'```.  The ```2020-09-12 20:00:00``` is something  JPA and/or jooq is doing.

Comment: I just realized you have ```LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.AUGUST, 13, 0, 0``` and ```2020-09-12 20:00:00-04``` and say "This still seems correct.". I'm not seeing how that can be?

Comment: Oh my bad. I copied the wrong value: It is actually '2020-08-12 20:00:00-04'.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It pointed me to the right track. Now I am fixing the data when reading with a temp object.

Comment: @BluE: As I said, the best types to map to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` are `java.time.OffsetDateTime` (jOOQ's and JDBC's default choice), or `java.time.Instant` (which will cause the least amount of trouble in PostgreSQL). Why do you want to use a `LocalDateTime`? It depends on your client time zone.

Comment: @LukasEder I guess that is a point I don't get yet. I think of LocalDateTime being client neutral, because we only use LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC), so we never had a client time zone introduced. I think that JDBC/JOOQ assumption of it being client specific is wrong.

Comment: You are probably right that I should use 'java.time.Instant' instead though, because that assumption has been made in the past.

Comment: @LukasEder So if Instant would be the best replacement for LocalDateTime. What would be the best replacement for LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)?

Comment: [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now())

Comment: @LukasEder I mean for a date without time. Would you still use Instant for that? Also, what's the best db type to store a date without time in?

Comment: @BlueE: SQL `DATE` and `java.time.LocalDate`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create a temporary read object with OffsetDateTime and then converting it using `withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime()`. It was rather easy in the end to fix it. It was just counterintuitive from the start, that the db and/or jooq would convert the data to other time zones.

This is the new object:

```
public class PlannedInvoiceWithOffset
{
    private UUID accountId;
    private OffsetDateTime billingTime;
}
```

A new constructor for creating the desired data object and adjusting the time zone to UTC:

```
public PlannedInvoice(PlannedInvoiceWithOffset tempObject)
{
    this.accountId = tempObject.getAccountId();
    this.billingTime = tempObject.getBillingTime().withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
}
```

Now my read method looks like this:

```
public PlannedInvoice findByAccountId(UUID accountId)
{
    PlannedInvoiceWithOffset temp = dsl.selectFrom(PLANNEDINVOICE)
            .where(PLANNEDINVOICE.ACCOUNTID.eq(accountId.toString()))
            .fetchOneInto(PlannedInvoiceWithOffset.class);

    return new PlannedInvoice(temp);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don't solve this on a per-query or per-column basis, becasue everyone in your team will keep running into this problem if you don't get it right globally.